# ReferenceError while trying to call function of Item within Tab

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I tried to call functions of qml file from another qml file user component id but i am facing some issues. could some one help me out of this.
here is my code.

**Browser.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    function callme(message) {
        console.log(message)
    }
}
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 100
    TabView {
        id: tabView
        width: 640
        height: 50
        Tab {
            width: 100
            title: "Sample1.html"
            onVisibleChanged: {
                browser1.callme("hi")
            }
            Browser {
                id: browser1
            }
        }
        Tab {
            width: 100
            title: "Sample2.html"
            onVisibleChanged: {
                browser2.callme("bye")
            }

            Browser {
                id: browser2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error reported:

> ReferenceError: browser1 is not defined

Comment: Where did you include `Browser`?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014363/how-to-send-signals-between-tabs-of-tabview-qt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want access to items inside `Tab` control, you have to use its `item` property. I have changed your signal handler and it works:

```
...
onVisibleChanged: {
    item.callme("hi")
}

Browser{
  id: browser1
}
...
```

`Tab` control inherits from [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#status-prop) component. It takes its children as delegate and they are only created with the tab is activated. Most of the behavior is the same then the `Loader` component.

#### Experimentation for the record

What happend if we define two or more components inside a `Tab`? `Loader` component only accepts a delegate and the component created is accessed by `item` property. `Tab` component maps `children` property to `delegate` and you can define more than one, but I realized that **only the last child is created**.